Sleeping for a random amount of time in a stored procedure
A vendor application we're using utilizes multiple processes (not threads) spread across multiple computers, one for each processing core available. When asked for a batch of calculations, the application distributes the load between these engines, which then go to the database for additional details necessary to perform the computations.
As we add more cores -- and engines -- the simultaneous rush to the database causes a load spike so big, some engines start getting the ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred error, which causes them to crash (I know, it shouldn't, but we cannot fix the vendor's code). For example, with the engine-count of 1386, about 300 engines dump cores, because the 16-core Oracle cannot cope...
There is no official way to cause the application to stagger these engine-initializations...
But the first thing each engine is doing is invoke the same stored procedure -- which updates the same table -- and I'm wondering, if I can alter it to perform the staggering: cause each engine to sleep for random number of milliseconds.
What would the SQL snippet for this look like? Our servers run Oracle-19...

Within a PL/SQL block (or within your procedure), use DBMS_RANDOM to generate a random value and then DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP to sleep for that many seconds:
DECLARE
  seconds NUMBER := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 20);
BEGIN
  DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP( seconds );
END;
/

fiddle

Is there no way to use milliseconds?

@MikhailT. DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP( milliseconds / 1000 ); From the documentation you can use an accuracy of of hundredths of a second.

Actually, the documentation says, a hundreds of a second is the minimal increment possible. But that's good enough for us -- I was under impression, it must be an integer number of seconds, but that's not true... You may want to clear it up in your answer for posterity. Thanks.

@MikhailT. Hundredths, not hundreds. The documentation (linked in the previous comment) states "The smallest increment can be entered in hundredths of a second; for example, 1.95 is a legal time value." Since DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() generates a decimal value the answer above does generate a delay with hundredths of seconds accuracy - if you want different minimum and maximum delays then use something like DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0.01, 0.50).

If you are timing out on the connection, you'll never get to where you can use PL/SQL to do the staggering. Here are some other ideas:
(1) configure your listener to support more connections and give it more time. In listener.ora:
INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER=110
MAX_ALL_CONNECTIONS_LISTENER=1000
MAX_REG_CONNECTIONS_LISTENER=1000

(2) disable any listener logging in listener.ora:
LOGGING_LISTENER=OFF
LOGGING_LISTENER_SCAN1=OFF
LOGGING_LISTENER_SCAN2=OFF
LOGGING_LISTENER_SCAN3=OFF

(3) create more listeners. Each one can only work so hard to fork a shadow process and copy its memory, so a connection storm will bottleneck on a single listener process. You can create as many as you need. I have a system with 16 of them, each listening on a different port. If you use RAC and are going through the SCAN listener, each of these can be registered and it'll round-robin through them. If you aren't using RAC, you can perhaps have your clients randomize the port they use.
(4) add randomized sleep on the client side. In Unix, something like:
sleep `echo "\`echo | nawk -v seed=$$ '{srand(seed);print rand()*10}'\`/1" | bc 2>/dev/null`

(5) disable anything in the database slowing down those connections. Logon triggers are the first thing to check, followed by auditing (disable the logon audit trail), followed by any contention on updating the last logon date in USER$, which you can override by setting  _disable_last_successful_login_time=true in your initialization parms. All of these are removing unnecessary work that in an extreme login storm can cause a backup and timeouts.
I wish to underscore that all the above is for extreme cases, not for normal Oracle environments.

According to AWR presented to us by the DBA, it is not merely a connection-storm -- each successfully connected client proceeds to perform a somewhat expensive operation at the beginning -- they all query and then update the same table. And, no, we cannot stagger connections on the client-side -- this is a closed-source vendor-provided application.

@MikhailT., in that case, your reported ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred is misleading. It isn't about connect timeouts. And I'm giving you a laundry list of approaches to mitigate connection storms - use what you can, ignore what you can't. But as you're now telling me that it isn't at all about a connection storm, you can ignore my post and focus on normal SQL tuning. Actually fixing long running SQL is far more important that trying to add random delays into code.

The server is stormed by connections, but it would've coped, if they were simply connecting -- unfortunately, each (fortunate) connection proceeds to perform a somewhat expensive operation (the CPU-usage really spikes), which -- I suspect -- is made disproportionately impacting just by being so concentrated in time, which causes the "unfortunate" connection-attempts to time out. I do appreciate the other approaches you enumerated, we will test them too.

@MikhailT, when we speak of a "connection storm" and timeouts, it typically refers to the login itself, not to subsequent SQL activity those sessions may be doing. Given what you're now describing, I would ignore my suggestions above and focus exclusively on tuning the SQL that is causing the problem. You should be focused on making that SQL efficient, not on staggering its execution.
